# Setting up SSL on Nginx on AWS Ubuntu instance

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl

I currently have a NodeJS (Koa.js) / Angular4+ application sat on an AWS instance running Linux that I need to configure to use SSL. I have followed a few tutorials online, generated the SSL cert and attempted to get this working and so far I have had no luck.

Let me run you through what I have done so far:

I have generated the SSL certificate and it is in a file called ssl-bundle.crt in the /home/ubuntu directory on the instance. I also have the key sat in the same directory.

I have configured my server block on Nginx for the application as follows (/etc/nginx/sites-available/dashboard.conf):

```
server {
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443;

        ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/ssl-bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/dashboard.d*****d.key;

        ssl on;
        ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log            /var/log/nginx/d*****d.access.log;

        location / {
               proxy_set_header Host $host;
               proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
               proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
               proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
}
```

The Node application is running on port 4000 so I have a proxy_pass to that address when someone access that url. When I don't use SSL the application runs fine when accessing that URL, but when I attempt to use the above server block code trying to access the URL causes a time out. Can anyone help me here or see what is wrong with my configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to list the SSL certificate and keyfile path in your node server configuration file. You can list this either in index.js or app.js file.

The question has already been answered on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34084621/apache-and-nodejs-over-ssl) earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this wasn't an Nginx issue but an issue with the AWS security group. I hadn't allowed 443 as an incoming port in the settings. Once I did this it worked fine. Hope this helps anyone in future using AWS.